# Angular4 : ngFor getting confused by dynamically modified arrays

Tags: angular

Here is my template :

```
     <div *ngFor="let d of data; let i=index">
        <select [(ngModel)]="d.dob" name="dob-{{i}}">
          <option *ngFor="let d of [1990, 1991, 1992]">
            {{d}}
          </option>
        </select>
        <i class="fa fa-times" (click)="remove(i)"></i>
      </div>
      <button type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary"
          (click)="add()"
          > + </button>
```

here is my component:

```
data: any[] = []
add(): void {
  this.data.push({dob: undefined})
}

remove(index: number): void {
  this.data.splice(index, 1)
}
```

For some reasons, when I have 2 selects, then start removing the first one, and add a new one, the value in the first one (which was the second at first) disapears.

It seems I should retrigger a rendering as the template is getting confused by the reference. I managed to get rid of the issue by addding

```
this.data= _.cloneDeep(this.data)
```

in my `add` function

Any cleaner way to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `trackBy` option on *`ngFor` when the items are dynamically added or removed.

**HTML**

```
 <div *ngFor="let d of data; let i=index; trackBy: trackByFn">
```

**Typescript:**

```
trackByFn(index, item) {
    return index; 
}
```

> When the contents of the iterator changes, NgForOf makes the
>   corresponding changes to the DOM:
>
> When an item is added, a new instance of the template is added to the
>   DOM. When an item is removed, its template instance is removed from
>   the DOM. .... Otherwise, the DOM element for that item will remain the
>   same. Angular uses object identity to track insertions and deletions
>   within the iterator and reproduce those changes in the DOM.
>
> To customize the default tracking algorithm, NgForOf supports trackBy
>   option. trackBy takes a function which has two arguments: index and
>   item. If trackBy is given, Angular tracks changes by the return value
>   of the function.

[Docs](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#change-propagation)

Comment: I was thinking about it, but not sure what fields should I reference in my trackBy ?

Comment: Great post, I am gonna try it out tomorrow, and accept the answer if it solves my issue :)

Comment: It did indeed solve my problem on all browsers by IE, so I am gonna dig it out. But cheers mate

Comment: Ok I solved the IE issue by adding [ngValue] on <option>